# SQL Command with string as Tablename

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

```
private DataTable zGetTableContent(string tablename)
{
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Connection.Open();

        MessageBox.Show(tablename);

        Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM '%" + tablename + "%'", Connection);
        Adapter.Fill(dt);

        Connection.Close();
        return dt;
}
```

Trying to get the above code working, but struggling with it. I guess I'm doing something wrong with the string. But can't figure out what.

The string is perfectly transferred to the method. MessageBox shows the correct string. But my adapter says

> Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause

If I type in the tablename by myself, everything works fine.

**EDIT:**

The connected database (Access):

```
    static private OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection();

    private void zPrepConnect(string SourceFile)
    {
        Connection.ConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source = {0};", SourceFile);
        Command.Connection = Connection;
    }
```

**EDIT #2:**
Tablenames are as followed:

- rstw
- simis is
- simis w
- simis c

**EDIT #3:**
Removed spaces from tablenames but still not working:

- rstw
- simis_is
- simis_w
- simis_c

Comment: What database are you trying to query?

Comment: What is the value of tablename? There is where the error lies.

Comment: How about `"SELECT * FROM " + tablename + "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need ' or % signs in the query, just go with name:

```
  Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + tablename + "]", Connection);
```

Check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) to be sure about syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already tried that one. Computer says no ;-) I get "Syntax Error in FROM clause."

Comment: What is your table name? Is it somehow SQL-reserved name? Like user? Then just go with [TableName] syntax, but you still don't need % or ' symbols, that would 100% result in error.

Comment: The problem is space in your table name, just use [Table Name] syntax

Comment: But I also get an error when I select "rstw" and there's no space in it.

Comment: What error? Please, add a stack trace of that. Query: "SELECT * FROM [rstw]" is perfectly legal.

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm so sorry. Havn't seen your update in your answer. now I know what you ment by [tablename]. Problem solved, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `string.Format`:

```
string query = string.Format ("select * from \"{0}\" ", TableName);
```